# getting "xxx is not a function" in JS

Tags: javascript, html

here's a little code I try to run on Firefox:

```
    <html>



    <head>


        <title>Ex4: My Sequence Finder</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        function action() {
            alert("action");
                if (formValidation() == false)
                    return;
        }

        function searchInput() {
            alert("searchInput");
            return;

        }


        </script>



    </head>



<body>



    <font face="arial" size="5" color="blue">Input section</font> <br/>

    <p>Query Sequence</p>

    <form name="form">

    <textarea id="input" rows="8" cols="60"></textarea><br/>

    <textarea id="enhancers" rows="4" cols="30"></textarea><br/>

    <textarea id="silencers" rows="4" cols="30"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="button" value="button1" onclick="action()" />
    <input type="button" value="button2" onclick="searchInput()" />

    <div id="results"></div>

    </form>



</body>



</html>
```

As you can see one of the button calls searchInput() and that works fine, the other
is supposed to call action(), but I get "action() is not a function". Btw they both just call alert() at this point, so I know it got in the function.

I have no idea as to why this happens, any help would be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form elements have an [`action`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-action) attribute (specifying the URI that should process the form data).

This attribute name "overrides" the javascript function name, causing the error you see.

Rename your function to something else and it will work.

Comment: @Felix - I once spent hours with a non functioning `submit()` function :)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using

```
var function1 =new function(){
          var action=new  function() {
                alert("action");
                    if (formValidation() == false)
                        return;
            }
    }
<input type="button" value="button1" onclick="function1.action()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`action` calls `formValidation` which doesn't seem to be a function. Maybe the parser took this error and chose not te register action as a function because of it.